# restricting users on nodejs telegram bot

Tags: node.js, bots, telegram, restrict

I currently have a telegram bot giving my organisation users answers to FAQ questions 
but I need to restrict it so only certain people that have paid for the mentorship are able to use the product

is there anyway I can ask people to enter a user id number that stores the information 
in so if there not on the list in the code there cant access the bot

my bot is currently written in nodejs language (based on [this repo](https://github.com/Xfox1/telegrambotautoresponder)).

```
[
    {
        "triggers": [
            "hello",
            "hi"
        ],
        "replies": [
            {
                "reply": "Hi Im your Personal Lion Bot \r\n\r\nWhat do you want to focus on today\r\n\r\n>Trading Help\r\n\r\n>Business Help\r\n\r\n>Mindset\r\n\r\n>Schedule\r\n\r\n>Just Started\r\n\r\n>Help",
                "type": "text"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "triggers": [
            "trading",
            "Trading"
        ],
        "replies": [
            {
                "reply": "Ok you want to focus on trading\r\n\r\nHeres is what I can show you\r\n\r\n>Our Schedule\r\n\r\n>A Trading Gameplan\r\n\r\n>Trade Ideas\r\n\r\n>Trading Products",
                "type": "text"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: please share a snippet of the bot code (handler you wish to restrict access to)

Comment: hi over added it to the main message

Comment: what library are you using? I only see a JSON, no logic.. are you using some cloud solution?

Comment: its currently runs off my computer using npm install and npm start function on the computer terminal

Comment: what library? what did you install with `npm install`? what's inside `dependencies` section of your `package.json` file?

Comment: "homepage": "https://github.com/Xfox1/telegrambotautoresponder#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^7.0.0",
    "node-telegram-bot-api": "^0.30.0"
  }
}

Comment: thats what that section says

Answer (score 0):

You need to know your paying users' ID, then you answer their messages only if `msg.from.id` is in your list of allowed users.

Something like:

```
function check_if_allowed(id) {
  ...
}

bot.on('message', (msg) => {
  if (check_if_allowed(msg.from.id)) {
    ...
  }
})
```

To find their ID depends on how you register them in your organization.

Add more details and code if you need further help

Comment: Thank you
How do you make the actual List sorry I’m totally new to this

Comment: @AlShan Apart from making the list, if the above answer is correct please mark it as accepted, so others can use it. It would be a good idea to implement the answer with a fake list and see if it works. Then you should open a new thread asking how to capture user id after subscription

Comment: @AlShan It really depends on how you process the users that pay for mentorship. If they buy it from a web page, then you could give them an invite link like t.me/mentorship_bot?start=123456 and then you read the code when you process the /start command, and associate this code to the user id. Tell more about your process and show your code if you need more help